# can i assign the id for localstored objects in html5

Tags: html, local-storage

i am new for html5 and web designing....
My html form contains username and password textfields.
Can i store username and passwords are localstore(client-side store) ?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only strings are supported.
You could store your username and password using

```
localStorage['username']='myusername';
localStorage['password']='mypassword';
```

and retrieve them using just

```
var username = localStorage['username'];
var password = localStorage['password'];
```

an alternative is to create a credentials object like this:

```
var credentials = {username:'myusername', password:'mypassword'};
```

since this is an object, jo have to stringify it in order to store it in localstorage

```
localStorage['credentials'] = JSON.stringify(credentials);
```

and to retrieve

```
var storedCredentials = JSON.parse(localStorage['credentials']);
```

Comment: thanks....i'm new to html5, i am using safari 4.0.4 browser, i download **WebKit-SVN-r92573.zip** file and Extract files to zip file, when double-click on the EXE file then alert window will appearance, the alert window content is **The procedure entry point u_strToUpper_4_0 could not be located in  the dynamic link library icuuc40.dll** what i'm doing for install for webkit browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Just create a wrapper object

var mydata = { username : username, password : password }

and store this in localStorage.

Comment: thanks... I am using safari 4.0.4 browser, i download WebKit-SVN-r92573.zip file and Extract files to zip file, when double-click on the EXE file then alert window will appearance, the alert window content is The procedure entry point u_strToUpper_4_0 could not be located in the dynamic link library icuuc40.dll what i'm doing for install for webkit browser?

Comment: This is not a webkit support forum. Please ask another question for another matter.